# Distortion in the UV editor

Tags: materials, shaders, transforms, uv-image-editor

In the image below, bottom-left, the skew in the UV editor causes the imported image to distort. You can see the distortion if you zoom in close to the image in the 'shading'at the top-right.

How can I straighten the selected portion that is skewed in the UV editor?

[image]

Comment: Maybe unwrap with the Follow Active Quads option, or Project From View?